# python - change dict keys in a queryset of values

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have something like this: `model.objets.values('id', 'name')` that returns a list of dicts with 'id' and 'name' as the keys. Is there a way that I can pass custom names to those keys? Something like: `model.objets.values('id', 'name').column_names('main id', 'name of de thing I want')`?

I'm using python + django

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can use named arguments, and make use of [**`F`** expressions <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) instead:

```
from django.db.models import F

Model.objects.values(main_id=F('id'), my_name=F('name'))
```

In case the "target names" are not valid Python identifiers, you can make use of *dictionary unpacking*:

```
from django.db.models import F

Model.objects.values(**{'main_id': F('id'), 'name with spaces': F('name')})
```

That being said, it is often advisable to use [*serializers* <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) than using `.values()` as a way to produce JSON blobs.